# How to plot a dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns "time" (dates) and "count" and I want to plot it, with the time on the x-axis and the counts as the y-axis..

```
df = df[['time','count']]
```

```
plt.plot('time','count')
```

Comment: Just use `df.plot` accessor, `df[['time','count']].plot()`

Comment: `plt.plot(df['time'], df['count'])`